# Leaflet's worldCopyJump breaks map, zooming fixes it up (updated)

Tags: leaflet, markers

I had my map working with `worldCopyJump` set to `true`, but then it stopped working. I'm not sure exactly what broke it (the original form of this question said there was a connection to a plugin, but that doesn't seem to be the case), but it might be that I updated to Leaflet 0.62.

In any case, this is the problem: when the map loads, dragging the map would throw a bunch of errors claiming to have invalid LatLong objects (with a `NaN` instead of the longitude), and the map would freeze.

Oddly enough, if *before dragging* the map I zoomed in or out, and *then* dragged, everything would work fine. Whatever the map is doing during `onzoom` seems to be somehow fixing whatever problem it had.

Also peculiar is the LatLongs that are reported to be invalid: they are nowhere in the code. I have no idea where those numbers might be coming from.

I traced the error back to the `worldCopyJump` option. If this is set to `false` then the map works from the get go. But I need that option turned on. Can anybody think of what might be going on?

You can find a (non-)functional version of the map online [here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucjt465/debug.html).

In case that does not last, here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.2/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.2/leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    html, body, #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = L.map('map',{
        center: [35.67989, 139.76463],
        zoom: 2,
//         Set followign line to false or comment out to fix problem
        worldCopyJump: true,
      }
    );

  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/{styleId}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    key: "YOURCLOUDMADEKEY",
    styleId: 97789,
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map);

  L.marker([50.5, 30.5]).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turns out this has nothing to do with the MarkerCluster plugin in the end. I still have no idea why it's not working, but I kept on trimming down the code, removed the GeoJSON, removed the references to the plugin, even removed the layer control... all to no avail. I updated the code in the question to reflect these changes, and the online version has them as well. Still lost though...

Comment: Indeed, going back to Leaflet 0.5 fixes the problem. Not sure if this is a bug or if I'm using something wrong, though...

Comment: Filed a bug report and a solution has been added. See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/1833